# how create Adaptive ,non-linear, fuzzy controller in ROS?

Tags: ros, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi .
how create Adaptive ,non-linear, fuzzy  controller in ROS ?? is it possible ?? i need some Advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255045/how-create-adaptive-,non-linear,-fuzzy--controller-in-ros-??/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it would be rather easy to clone the [PID package](http://wiki.ros.org/pid) and replace the relevant parts of controller.cpp with whatever you need. If it works well, you could make a pull request to have it added.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-02-20**:
Now that I look at it, the PID package has fancy features you wouldn't need. Maybe better to look at the less-popular [lyap_control](http://wiki.ros.org/lyap_control) package. It's simpler and supports multiple inputs, multiple outputs. Again, replace everything except `main()` in controller.cp